# Why suddenly PHP adds the string 'null' to a string?

Tags: php

I suddenly have this strange behavior in PHP. I looked around here but cannot find a reasonable explanation

I have an extremely simple example:

```
<?php
   $test = 'hello123';
   print $test;
?>
```

This shows: **hello123null** in the webbrowser.
When I echo instead of print the result, its the same.
When I put the string in double quotes also the same.

No matter what I do, it always appends the string 'null' to it.

What is happening here?

Comment: In my case it prints without additional `null` text. Why you don't want to use `echo` or `print_r()`?

Comment: no i am executing this , it shows `hello123`

Comment: It used to show hello123 here too. But now suddenly it appends this string 'null' to every end of a string. I just echo or print it, because I ran into some issues and I needed to check if variables are correct. Then I discovered this. VERY weird. Echo or print results in the same issue.

Comment: i think there are some code that print null other than this code, can you give us some detail of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When serving web pages and mixing HTML and PHP there are scenarios where you can flush hidden characters.

**How to troubleshoot:**

1. Turn on show all characters in the IDE so you can see spaces, line breaks, etc.
2. Verify no other pages are executed after that script. Sometimes when flipping between HTML and PHP extra characters are injected in the view if you are not following best practices.
3. Put another print line after your print hello123, is it still after hello123 or your last command?

   ```
   ("hello123");
   print("test");
   ```
4. Try `obflush ()` to pin point issue:
   see https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-flush.php

   ```
   print("hello123");
   ob_flush();
   flush();
   print("test");
   ```
5. Lastly, try setting your header.

   `header( 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );`